# Continuity of the map $r(x)= \frac{x}{\|x\|}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Consider the map $r: \mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0\} \rightarrow S^n$ (from a real punctured plane to the sphere) given by  $r(x)=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$. Evidently, this map is continuous. I tried to apply the standard $\epsilon\text{-}\delta$ definition of continuity to verify that it is continuous, but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there any other way to verify its continuity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $x\mapsto\|x\|$ is continuous and strictly positive away from $0$, therefore, the map
$$x\longmapsto\frac{1}{\|x\|}$$
is continuous on $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$, and so on. Here I'm just using the standard rules about compositions of continuous functions giving continuous functions, etc.

Comment: So this means $r(x)$ is the composite of $f(x)=x$ and $x\mapsto 1/||x||$?

Comment: No, that composite would give you $x\mapsto\frac{1}{\|x\|}$ as $f(x)=x$ is the identity. The function you want it the *product* of $x\mapsto x$ and $x\mapsto\frac{1}{\|x\|}$.